# Не создает инстанс класса из строки

Tags: php, namespace

Не создает инстанс класса из строки которая содержит неймспейс и название класса. Если не использовать `USE` все работает, а вот с `USE` не хочет

```
Рабочий вариант:

    <?php

    namespace SE_Core\Test;

    class Main
    {
        public function show()
        {

        }
    }

    $className = 'Main';

    $class = 'SE_Core\Test\\' . $className;

    $obj = new $class();

    print_r($obj);

    ?>

Нерабочий вариант:

<?php

namespace SE_Core\Test;

use SE_Core\Test as SE;

class Main
{
    public function show()
    {

    }
}

$className = 'Main';

$class = 'SE\\' . $className;

$obj = new $class();

print_r($obj);

?>
```

Comment: @splash58 с чего вдруг так получается? `use` это всего лишь алиас. А вот вообще зачем использовать полные имена находят в этом же самом пространстве имен - вопрос. Да и делать алиас к текущему пространству. Тем более что этот `use` действует только в рамках данного файла, то есть передать это никуда не получится.

Comment: Это я взял на скорую руку для демонстрации ошибки

Comment: @teran а без он тоже не находит - https://eval.in/909088

Comment: Без use у меня дает инфу об объекте, все нормально

Comment: @splash58 а и не должен, при динамическом создании полное имя обязательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работает, поскольку алиасы, определенные с помощью `use` распространяются только на текущий файл, и что самое важное - имеют смысл только на этапе *компиляции* кода, во время выполнения они не существуют. Поэтому ничего удивительного в том, что класс не находится - нет. Это не является ошибкой, а особенность языка, так пхп устроен.

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> Импорт выполняется во время компиляции, и не влияет на имена
>   **динамических классов**, функций или констант.

В оригинале:

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic
>   class, function or constant names.

вероятно, более удачным был бы перевод "*...и поэтому не затрагивает...*"

Цитата из раздела документации ["PHP: Основы"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php)

> Если с директивой `new` используется строка (`string`), содержащая имя
>   класса, то будет создан новый экземпляр этого класса. Если имя
>   находится в пространстве имен, то оно должно быть задано полностью.

Comment: Не совсем конечно понял разница использования new SE\Class и если бы я SE поместил в стринг

Comment: @quaresma89 дополнил ответ еще одной цитатой документации. а SE, как уже написано выше вообще недоступно во время выполнения кода, это т.н. синтаксический сахар доступный во время парсинга и компиляции кода. в момент выполнения кода, пхп ничего не знает о вашем `SE`.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно, спасибо